# Space Efficiency - Geotiff File VS Postgis Raster

Tags: postgis, geotiff-tiff

Is it more space efficient to store a raster as a geotiff file on disk or directly in Postgis?

I ask because I currently have a large number of rasters stored in a Postgis database and I want to instead store them out-db where Postgis just holds pointers to the .tif files (using raster2psql -R option).

Should I expect an increase in disk space used after this migration? Assume that I stay with 32 bit floating point for both storage methods.

Comment: This ought to be fairly easy to test. Load a few and check size with pg_total_relation_size or similar.

Comment: in addition to what John said, if you're on linux, use "df" which will tell you your free disk space.  "df", add raster to database, "df", and note the difference and compare to size of tiff file.  using "df" will account for any indexes, etc that get stored invisibly.